# Python: Join two tables and get values from a column in one of the table

Tags: python, mysql, join

I have two tables

- closed_resturants
- reviews

Both of them have a column named  `business_id`. The `reviews` table has a column named `text_reviews`.

I want to get the text_reviews corresponding to each business_id in `closed_restaurants` table and put the `text_reviews` into a list.

How can I do that in python?

Comment: Welcome to SO: We encourage you to take the tour and in particular, read [MCVE] which may help you to craft a question that increases your chances of getting the help that you need. We need much more information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have not made it very clear what you are using for a connector to your database or any of your code. The task can be completed with a MySQL call such as...

```
SELECT text_reviews 
FROM reviews, closed_restaurants 
WHERE closed_restaurants.business_id = reviews.business_id
```

you could use this to populate your cursor with the responses and then store them into variables as strings.